# Script - How to check if a network path is available and then map it

Tags: windows, networking, script, login, vbscript

I would like an screen saver / logon script that checks if a network path is available and then map it to a unit. If it is not available it disconnects/don't connect.

Network path is \192.168.1.1\drive1

Also I need to use username/password to connect to that path.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `exist` command to check if the path is valid:

```
if exist \\192.168.1.1\drive1 net use s: \\192.168.1.1\drive1
```

If you need to provide credentials (i.e. your current Windows user doesn't have access to that share), add `/user`:

```
if exist \\192.168.1.1\drive1 net use s: \\192.168.1.1\drive1 /user:myDomain\myUser myPassword
```

If there's a chance that the share already exists, and you want to delete it if it's no longer available, add an `else` clause:

```
if exist \\192.168.1.1\drive1 (net use s: \\192.168.1.1\drive1) else (net use /delete s:)
```

And once again, add the `/user` if you need it.

You can tie this all together in a batch file similar to the following:

```
@echo off
if exist \\192.168.1.1\drive1 (set shareExists=1) else (set shareExists=0)
if exist y:\ (set driveExists=1) else (set driveExists=0)
if %shareExists%==1 if not %driveExists%==1 (net use y: \\192.168.1.1\drive1)
if %shareExists%==0 if %driveExists%==1 (net use /delete y:)
set driveExists=
set shareExists=
```

Comment: ok I am just pasting that in notepad and saving as .vbs but when I run a task of it it gives Visual basic error?

Comment: That command is a batch command - it should work from any standard batch file.

Comment: C:\Windows>if exist \\192.168.1.1\volume1 (net use y: \\192.168.1.1\volume1 )  e
lse (net use /delete y: )
The network connection could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250.

Comment: I'll add an edit...

Comment: i'm sorry? (5 chars)

Comment: I added an extra piece to my answer - see the bottom batch file

Comment: Would "if exist" also confirm if the shared network path is accessible or not?  Similar to how one would manually click the link to make sure it isn't down?

Comment: How to check the status of the mapped drive? It can be OK, Disconnected, Unavailable

Comment: @user1602 That's a different issue - submit a new question, after searching to see if it has already been answered

Answer (score 6):

Powershell would make this easy:

```
If(Test-Path \\192.168.1.1\Drive1)
  {
    net use M: \\192.168.1.1\Drive1 /user:Domain\UserName Password
  }
else {net use M: /delete > nul}
```

Comment: ok I am just pasting that in notepad and saving as .vbs but when I run a task of it it gives Visual basic error?

Comment: Save it as a .ps1 and run it from Powershell.

Comment: i'm not familiar with powershell, how can I automate it in Task Scheduler?

Comment: You should really split the 2 questions. This is a QA site. Also, google it if you have not already: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&gs_rn=14&gs_ri=psy-ab&gs_mss=powershell%20expon&tok=ZC9KtwzSzpRllIS9eJ8tKw&pq=powershell%20exponent%20operator&cp=14&gs_id=10h&xhr=t&q=schedule+a+powershell+script&es_nrs=true&pf=p&biw=1920&bih=924&sclient=psy-ab&oq=schedule+a+pow&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.aWc&fp=1b7792c0858b391

Comment: ok got it. What the bonus of using powershell?

Comment: Can use the full .NET libraries, extensible through C#, can use native windows Commands... It has an ISE and IDEs through PowerGUI and others. Great syntax, automatic and explicit data types... In short it does ***everything***

Comment: powershell.exe : File C:\windows\logon.ps1 cannot be loaded because the executi
on of scripts is 
At line:1 char:11
+ powershell <<<<  -c c:\windows\logon.ps1 -verbose >> c:\windows\logon.txt 2>&
1
    + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (File C:\windows... of scripts is
   :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
At line:1 char:21
+ c:\windows\logon.ps1 <<<<  -verbose
    + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

Comment: ok I've set the restriction off.
now: net.exe : The network connection could not be found.
At C:\Windows\logon.ps1:7 char:10
+ else {net <<<<  use Y: /delete}
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The network con...d not be found.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8870/discussion-between-fernandosbs-and-athomsfere)

Answer (score 0):

It is just simplier to just try to map it using the Windows File explorer or using the net use command. Either it works or it doesn't.

Comment: If it's available I want to be automatically connected when I logon / screen saver, if it's not then I want it removed from the mapped drives. So what you suggested is not an option.

Comment: I don't understand, it you issue a net use, if the command succeeds it will be connected.  If the command fails, then it is removed from the mapped drives.  Seems simple to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code:

```
function run{
net use
If(Test-Path \\192.168.1.1\volume1)
  {
    if (((New-Object System.IO.DriveInfo("Y:")).DriveType -ne "NoRootDirectory")) 
        {
            "already mounted and accessible"
        }
    else
        {
            net use Y: \\192.168.1.1\volume1
            "mounting"
        }
  }
else { 
    if (((New-Object System.IO.DriveInfo("Y:")).DriveType -ne "NoRootDirectory"))
        {
            net use Y: /delete
            "removing"
        }
}
exit 4
}

run
```

I use `Test-Path \\192.168.1.1\volume1` as suggested to check if the network path is available and `((New-Object System.IO.DriveInfo("Y:")).DriveType -ne "NoRootDirectory")` to check if the drive letter exists.